# Turn on MSB of 8 bit integers

Tags: c

How to show the mask and turn on MSB of 8 bit integer?
I have tried different logical opeartors I am not getting right answers

Comment: Share what you've tried so far.

Comment: Which operators did you use, what did you do? Why not share with us? As you did not, we have to assume you have done nothing, so far. Note that logical operators are wrong here. You need a bit-operator.

Comment: The title says "Turn off MSB" but the question says "turn on MSB"... which is it?

Answer (score 3):

If you have an 8 bit integer then turning the MSB would be to set to '1' bit 7.

So the mask is 0x80 (only bit 7 is ON).

In order to set this bit you can use bit-wise OR `|`:

```
#define MSB_MASK 0x80 // or #define MSB_MASK (1 << 7)

int x;
x = x | MSB_MASK; // or x |= MSB_MASK; to make it shorter
```

Comment: FWIW: `x |= MASK;` is not just shorter, but also more clear, as you instantly see that `x` is modified. Not much of a problem here, but think about something like `p->b[index].my_very_very_very_long_member_name` instead of `x`. Also if manipulating all bits in a value, it is generally better to use unsigned types. As OP is asking particularily about 8 bits, the correct type is `uint8_t`.

Comment: @karthikpoojary Please note that you asked a very basic question. I would suggest to look for a C tutorial about bit-wise operators, it is not complicated but very useful.

Comment: @Olaf Of course. I just tried to make this answer be understandable. According to the asked question I wasn't sure that `x |= something;` will be clear enough. (He didn't actually specified if the type is signed or unsigned so I'll leave it as is for now)

Comment: Actually, I find the question OT here, as it is more like asking for a tutorial about bitops. As you already commented, such is definitively handled in a C tutorial or book. (Perhaps everyone wanting to ask a question should first answer three questions of this level before he is allowed to ask).

Answer (score 2):

Try this for Set MSB of 8 bit integer:

```
mask = mask|(1<<7)
```

To show the mask you can use:

```
char ch[9];
for (int i = 7; i>=0; i--) {
    ch[i] = (mask&1)+'0';
    mask >>= 1;
}
ch[8] ='\0';
printf("%s", ch);
```